# Java Android: App very slow on API23/22 but fluid on API19

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner in android development and for training purpose I've created a simple android app. This app is a "findWaldo" like game where player can zoom,pan and click on an image view. It uses a simple onTouch function in a  touchEventListener to manage events and basic math operations.

I ran this app on 3 physical devices:

- Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 Kitkat (API19): app is fluid and fast
- UMI Plus E (High Performance device) Marshmallow (API23): app is very slow (about 30 frames skipped)
- Galaxy A5 2014 Marshmallow (API 23): app is very slow (about 40 frames skipped)

**My question is:** why does my app run correctly on a quite old android OS (Kitkat)  but not on recent ones (Marshmallow)? And is there any good pratice or solution to avoid this ?

---

*Here is my code:*

**Game.java**

public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {

```
/* Define variables */
private RelativeLayout layout; /* activity layout */
private int[] images = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2}; /* Images list */
private float[][][] waldoC = {
        {
                {596f, 626f},
                {652f, 710f}
        },
        {
                {1100f, 290f},
                {1200, 380f}
        }
}; /* min and max coordinates of waldo click zone */
private int currentImage; /* index of displayed image */
private Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); /* Matrix to scale image */
private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix(); /* saved matrix during translate or scale */
private Float previousDist = 1f; /* Image scale */
private ImageView image; /* Image view used to display image */
private final static int NONE = 0; /* none event state */
private final static int PAN = 1; /* panning event state */
private final static int ZOOM = 2; /* zooming event state */
private int mEventState; /* event state */
private float mStartX; /* start position x for translating */
private float mStartY; /* start position y for translating */
private float mMidX; /* middle of two fingers positions x for scaling */
private float mMidY; /* middle of two fingers positions y for scaling */
private float[] values = new float[9]; /* array to get matrix values */
private final Handler delay = new Handler(); /* delay handler */
private boolean disabled = false; /* click enabled */
private Chronometer chronometer; /* chronometer */


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    /* Get layout */
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

    /* New thread to run chronometer */
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Getting chronometer */
            chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
            chronometer.start(); /* Chronometer start */
        }
    }).start();

    /* Getting image view */
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    /* Setting random image */
    image.setImageResource(randomImage());

    /* Setting on touch listenener to detect pinch zoom */
    image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        /* Touch event */
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            /* Getting image view */
            ImageView image = (ImageView) view;

            /* Checking if touch event are disabled */
            if(disabled == true){
                return true;
            }

            /* Detecting panning image events
             in switch condition, & is used to bitwise "event get action"
             result with "action mask" to get only action
             */
            switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: /* screen is touched */
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix); /* save matrix */
                    mEventState = PAN; /* change event state to pan */
                    mStartX = event.getX(); /* save start x and y positions */
                    mStartY = event.getY();
                    matrix.getValues(values); /* get matrix values in values array */
                    isClick(event, values[2], values[5], values[0]); /* call to click check */
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: /* screen is no more touched */
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mEventState = NONE; /* change event state to none */
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: /* move detected */
                    if(mEventState == PAN) { /* if event state is pan */
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix); /* matrix takes values of saved matrix */
                        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - mStartX, event.getY() - mStartY);
                        /* post concats translations on x and y */
                    }
                    else if(mEventState == ZOOM) { /* zoom detected */
                        float newDist = spacing(event); /* call to spacing */
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix); /* matrix takes values of saved matrix */
                        float scale = newDist / previousDist; /* determine scale */
                        focus(event); /* call to focus */
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mMidX, mMidY); /* post concats
                        to scale */
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: /* if multi touch is detected */
                    previousDist = spacing(event); /* call to spacing */
                    mEventState = ZOOM; /* change event state to zoom */
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix); /* save matrix */
                    break;
            }

            image.setImageMatrix(matrix); /* set matrix to image view */

            return true;
        }
    });
}

/* determine spacing between two fingers positions */
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    double x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    double y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/* determine focus point with 2 fingers positions */
private void focus(MotionEvent event) {
    mMidX = (event.getX(0) + event.getX(1))/2;
    mMidY = (event.getY(0) + event.getY(1))/2;
}

/* Randomize image */
private int randomImage(){
    Random r = new Random(); /* new random */
    currentImage = r.nextInt(images.length); /* generate random index
                                                in range of numebr of images */
    return images[currentImage]; /* returns image */
}

/* Check if touch event is a click to test waldo position */
private void isClick(MotionEvent event, final float translateX, final float translateY, final float scale){
    final Handler delay = new Handler(); /* delay handler */
    final MotionEvent e = event; /* create a final var for run function */

    /* wait for 1 second */
    delay.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if((e.getX() > mStartX - 10f && e.getX() < mStartX + 10f)) {
                /* if event does not move more than 10px, call to findWaldo */
                findWaldo(mStartX, mStartY, translateX, translateY, scale);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);

}

/* Check if click is on Waldo or not */
private void findWaldo(float x, float y, float translateX, float translateY, float scale){
        Log.d("POSITION", Float.toString(x - translateX) + " " + Float.toString(y - translateY));
        /* if x and y minus their translation correspond to Waldo area coordinates time scale */
        if((x - translateX >= waldoC[currentImage][0][0] * scale && x - translateX <= waldoC[currentImage][1][0] * scale)
            && (y - translateY >= waldoC[currentImage][0][1] * scale && y - translateY <= waldoC[currentImage][1][1] * scale)) {
                /* if waldo was found */
                ProgressBar spinner = new ProgressBar(this); /* create new spinner */
                spinner.setX(x - 100f); /* set spinner position around clicked position */
                spinner.setY(y);
                spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                /* change spinner color to green */
                layout.addView(spinner, 200, 200); /* add spinner to view with size of 200 */
                disableTouch(true); /* call to disable touch */
                chronometer.stop(); /* stop chronometer and end thread */
                hallOfFame((String) chronometer.getText()); /* call to hall fo fame */
        }
        else { /* if waldo was no found */
            final ProgressBar spinner = new ProgressBar(this); /* create new spinner */
            spinner.setX(x - 100f); /* set spinner position around clicked position */
            spinner.setY(y);
            spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            /* change spinner color to red */
            layout.addView(spinner, 200, 200); /* add spinner to view with size of 200 */
            disableTouch(true); /* call to disable touch */

            /* 2 seconds cooldown caused by player's error */
            delay.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    layout.removeView(spinner); /* remove spinner */
                    disableTouch(false); /* call to disable touch */
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
}

/* disable or enable touch events */
private void disableTouch(boolean value){
    disabled = value;
}

/* end the game */
private void hallOfFame(String time){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HallOfFame.class); /* new intent */
    i.putExtra("time", time); /* pass time to hall of fame actvity */
    startActivity(i); /* starts hall of fame activity */
    finish(); /* finish game activity */
}
```

}

**activity_game.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    tools:context="com.test.findwaldo.Game">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/gameTitle"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chronometer"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:scaleType="matrix"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: `Thank you so much in advance for your help.`. Why would anybody help you if you thank in advance?

Comment: @greenapps Because thanks are like congrats or diplomas, they don't have a meaning if they are related to nothing you've done.

Comment: They have the meaning that if i help you you will not thank me anymore. I'm not in for that.

Comment: Is there any rules that is saying "You can't thank twice" or anything ? It was just a polite way to conclude my post. Anyway, it looks like you're here to dicuss more about philosophical questions than code and Stackoverflow is not the good place. You'd better try here: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ .